# How to make a selection from two tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have table 'articles'

```
+-------------+
|   articles  |
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | title1 |
+----+--------+
| 2  | title2 |
+----+--------+
| 3  | title3 |
+----+--------+
```

table 'catalogue'

```
+---------------------+
|      catalogue      |
+----+--------+-------+
| id | group  | name  |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | group1 | name1 |
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | group1 | name2 |
+----+--------+-------+
| 3  | group2 | name3 |
+----+--------+-------+
| 4  | group2 | name4 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

binding table 'bindTable'

```
+------------+--------------+-------+
|              bindTable            |
+------------+--------------+-------+
| id_article | id_catalogue | value |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|     1      |      2       |   1   |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|     1      |      3       |   4   |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|     3      |      1       |   2   |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|     3      |      3       |   1   |
+------------+--------------+-------+
|     3      |      4       |   3   |
+------------+--------------+-------+
```

and i need to get result as in table 'result', where i can get pairs "catalogue_name : value" for selected item from table 'article'

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                        result                       |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
| article_id | article_title | catalogue_name | value |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
|      1     |     title1    |  group1_name2, |   1   |
|            |               |  group2_name3  |   4   |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
|      3     |     title3    |  group1_name1, |   2   |
|            |               |  group2_name3, |   1   |
|            |               |  group2_name4  |   3   |
+------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
```

Can anyone tell me a query string with one DB query? Thank you for attention.

```
My vision: 
    SELECT b.id_article, a.title, c.group, c.name, b.value 
    FROM bindTable b
    JOIN articles a ON a.id = b.id_articles
    JOIN catalogue c ON c.id = b.id_catalogue
    WHERE b.id_article = 1
```

but i need one row with pairs c.name&b.value for one a.id

Comment: value is also concat by  `,` like `catalogue_name` ?

Comment: it does not matter, only the name

Comment: What queries have you tried? Have you learned how to do JOINs?

Comment: does matter when desire output isnt clear. Please take you time to provide datailed requirement. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

A select with inner join

```
select a.article_id, a.article_title, b.catalogue_name, b.value
from bindTable as c
inner join articles as a on a.id = c. article_id
inner join catalogues as b on c. id_catalogue = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
SELECT articles.id AS article_id, 
       articles.title AS article_title, 
       CONCAT_WS('_', catalogue.group, catalogue.name) AS catalogue_name,
       bindTable.value AS value
FROM bindTable
  INNER JOIN articles ON bindTable.id_article = articles.id
  INNER JOIN catalogue ON bindTable.id_catalogue = catalogue.id
```

Comment: I dont think you need a `LEFT JOIN` a simple `INNER JOIN` should work

Comment: Indeed it would, thanks for the comment I will update my answer.

Comment: sorry for my english, i search by 'title' from 'articles' and i need to add to result table corresponding fields for title id from table catalogue and its value with binding table, as example, for title1 from articles i get two overlapping field from table 'bindtable' with id '1', and with value '1' and '4'. In table 'catalogue' by found id i get its name: "group1 name2" & "group2 name3". Finally i need something as 'title1' | "group1 name2 = 1" | "group2 name3 = 4"

Comment: @Alaksander Dont write it as a comment Update your question and let us know.

Comment: @Alaksander sorry buddy I can't understand what it is you want, please can you include an example of the output you would like to achieve just like you did for your data sources?

Comment: It's your query return:

3, title3, group1_name1, 2
1, title1, group1_name2, 1
1, title1, group2_name3, 4
3, title3, group2_name3, 1
3, title3, group2_name4, 3

Your answer is right, but it return all fields, i want get anything like this:

1, title1, (group1_name2=1; group2_name3=4)
or
1, title1, (group1_name2; group2_name3), (1; 4)

Where id = 1, and I want pairs "catalogue_name:value" as "group1_name2:1" and "group1_name2:4"
may be it is impossible by sql and I need PHP handle your variant

Comment: @Steve Moore I want to show on client side table, where items sorting by title from atricles table and will be contain list of names and groups from catalogue table with it's values from binding table in one row by one title. May be my DB variant is not good and I need to repair content of each table. Excuse Me for my english again...

Comment: @Alaksander It's not that it's impossible but it is a little unusual that you would structure/format your data like this in a SQL result. I would normally generate these key value pairs in PHP (or other server side software) ready for use.

Comment: @Steve Moore Each title - it is a music score, and pairs "group_name":"value" - a set "music instrument":"values", where each music instrument is id from catalogue - list of all music instrument. In result table I need to show rows with title and one row field contain list of all instruments for this music score and their values. May be your propose me other variant of relations "music score":"list of music instruments and their values"